# Create direct link to a task without login in processmaker

Tags: processmaker

I'm working on a project in ProcessMaker, it's a simple purchase order process. In one of the steps, i need the providers to input the price and availability of the products, but no matter where i search, i cannot find a option similar to a "web entry", but for a specific task that doesn't need a login.

The ProcessMaker people give an explample in their website, but it's not really very well explained.

https://www.processmaker.com/running-purchase-request-process

They just show the result, but they don't give any hints off how that can be acomplished. (Talking about where they say that one can generate a link and send it to the providers for them to fill out the form online)

Can any one help me? I'm using community edition by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is only available in the Enterprise edition. You can do it through a custom plug-in, buy that requires writing php code.